How best can I explain my three years of unemployment during my PhD applications?
I am from an Asian country, 29 years old. I did my bachelor's and did a year of internships in R&D. I then got accepted into a good master's program in an EU country and got a job as a research technician in another EU country soon after. I worked there for 5 months but got laid off and also had a terrible boss that mentally affected me a lot.
I returned home, trying to do PhD and job applications to go back to EU, nothing seems to be panning out. I have done nothing in the past 3 years (I also gave up and stopped applying in the middle because of mental health issues).
I did one year of freelancing in a completely unrelated area, but nothing else. I am very passionate about doing a PhD in biomedical research. I have the following questions :

what are my chances realisticallys to get accepted into a PhD program in Europe due to this 3 year gap?

How best can I explain the gap in my application or motivation letter?

Is it okay to say "I was talking care of older family member" rather than mentioning my mental health issues in my cover letter to explain the gap? (even though it wasn't really the case - it is my own chronic depression)

Can I also be vague in my resume and day that I did some freelancing during this time. Will universities in Europe check for the freelancing history for the application process?



Were you taking care of a older family member?

Not really, I was mostly dealing with mental health issues, but i am not keen on putting that on my application letter.

Well, certainly don't lie to anyone ...

I lightly edited your post, but I would suggest you reorient this into something actionable. We can't tell you that it will drop you from 50% chance to 20% chance of getting in somewhere. You can't change anything, so ask a question about what to do.

Hey, I think this question here is very similar: Should I just stop applying for admission to PhD with my research gap of 8 years?. There were many comments there that I think might help you understand what you might be facing in your submission processes.

I can't speak for Asia, but understanding of MH concerns, especially when diagnosed are becoming more accepted in the West. I'm sure you won't be the only applicant that briefly explains a gap due to MH issues.

You have a longer gap, but the responses to Should I mention about the time wasted (6 months) due to depression in my CV when I will apply to PHd programs may be informative.

Have you got your mental issues sorted? PhD is not a cakewalk. Your health is more important than you doing a PhD.

there is another question on the same topic that I think might be very similar to your case: Should I just stop applying for admission to PhD with my research gap of 8 years?
Now to your questions:

Is it going to be impossible for me to get accepted into a PhD program
in Europe due to this 3 year gap?

No, many programs accept people from different backgrounds, and many supervisors don't bother with that. Some do, and they are going to reject your submission. But you should look at those as a good sign that you dodged a bullet.

Is it okay to say "I was talking care of older family member" rather
than mentioning my mental health issues in my cover letter to explain
the gap?

As others have already said, don't lie in your cover letter. Lying to your potential supervisor will harm you more than a three-year gap. Just be honest and try to spin it into something that might make you a better candidate. PhD is an arduous and long journey, it might be good that you are more conscious about your mental health and you know how to deal with that.

Can I also be vague in my resume and day that I did some freelancing during this time. Will universities in Europe check for the freelancing history for the application process?

Did you do this freelancing? If they checked, would that be bad? Again, don't lie to your potential supervisor. It will be worse once they discover it. You don't need to be 100% honest if you are uncomfortable, but don't lie in any documents or conversations with them. If you did freelancing, you probably should talk about it. PhD is a big and long project. Having experience with project and time management is good for a PhD application.

Speaking from my experience now. In the UK, there are many types of candidates for a PhD: people with no research experience and fresh out of their master's, older candidates with industrial experience trying to change careers, people with gap years, and everything in between. There is no reason to be overly anxious about your situation. For me, the best thing you can do is find contacts that work on your research interests. They might know a supervisor looking for a student for a particular project. You should also try to do some research on your own (if possible in your field), which will show interest and show that you know how to do research. You don't even have to publish anything. Remember, the application process serves to find the students that best align with the supervisor's expectations. If you fit in those, the 3-year gap will make no difference.
Best of luck to you!

What you describe does not look good. The following stand out:

You worked as a research technician and got laid off after 5 months. Although it's not as serious as being fired, it still suggests that they don't think you're a very valuable employee.
You then apparently did nothing for two, arguably three, years. This is a long time. Since you've barely worked (i.e., earned a salary) up till now, it's improbable that you can fund such a long career break. In turn, it suggests that someone - presumably your parents - was subsidizing you, which looks bad on your ability to be independent.
You claim that you are very passionate about biomedical research. Considering that you apparently did nothing for 2-3 years, this is hard to believe. Someone who is very passionate about biomedical research would at least get some things done (like take some courses at the local university).
Your defense against all these is that you had mental health issues. However, three years is a long time. Are you actually recovered, or are you going to relapse after admission?

You'll need to explain all these things in your statement. Since it sounds like freelancing was the only constructive thing you did in the last three years, it's probably a good idea to elaborate on that, especially if it's related to biomedical research. You might also want to get your recommendation-writers / doctor to vouch for your mental health issues, since it could look like an excuse.
